# How to give 777 permission while creating a zip folder in php

Tags: php, linux, permissions, 777

I am trying to create a zip folder but I'm not able to give 777 permission. Please help me out this.

Here is my source code:

```
 $files = ['13150925581920IMG_0009.PNG','1328684363792113286843637921IMG_0009.PNG'];
 $random = rand(1111111111,9999999999);
 $zipname = 'photos_'.$random.'.zip';

 $zip = new ZipArchive;
 $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
 chmod($zipname, 777);

 foreach ($files as $file) {
   if(file_exists($file)){
     $zip->addFromString(basename($file),  file_get_contents($file));  
   }
 }

 $zip->close();

 header('Content-Type: application/zip');
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
 readfile($zipname);

 header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zipname");
 header("Content-length: " . filesize($zipname));
 header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
 header("Expires: 0"); 
 readfile("$zipname");
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? Why (do you think you) aren't you able to give 777?

Comment: I am not getting any error message

Comment: So why do you think you are not able to give 777 permission then?

Comment: Because zip folder is not created

Comment: So the error is that your zip file `photos_'.$random.'.zip` is not created and not that the permission are not applied - correct?

Comment: Yes, zip file photos_'.$random.'.zip is not created

Comment: Can you please check what the returrn value of `$zip->open` is?

Comment: $zip-open is return this "ZipArchive Object ( [status] => 0 [statusSys] => 0 [numFiles] => 0 [filename] => /var/www/html/admin/photos_1334378055.zip [comment] => )"

Comment: Do you actually need to save it to disk? If you're just sending it for download directly then why not create a temporary archive as per one of the examples at https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php . Unless your file is huge then it should be ok

Comment: Move the `chmod` to after you close the ZIP file if you really need it saved to disk. But even then why the 777?

Comment: Remove php open tag

Comment: check the manual, you need to prefix the mode with 0 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php